# Create Executable jar file from Gradle and import jar in maven

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar

hello I have created one spring boot project with gradle configuration which contains common functionalities like authentication, social login and I want to make executable jar file and make as dependency from gradle project so I can import it into another spring gradle or maven project in order to access REST end point of included dependency

**(Project A : which wants to make as libarary)**

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

springBoot.mainClassName = "com.example.auth"
bootJar.enabled = true

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.auth'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

project also contains end point like

```
package com.example.auth;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("testCalled")
    public String testCalled(){
        return "test called..";
    }
}
```

and It created a jar file using gradle build command and installed as dependency into another project using :

```
mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=F:\auth\build\libs\auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" -DgroupId=com.auth -DartifactId=test-authentication -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and it also installed dependency successfully

**Project B : Spring boot maven project**

i want to use rest end point

> /api/test/testCalled

from maven project (project B)

Any idea then please help !!

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want an executable jar, you want/need a regular jar. Spirng Boot repackes the jar to a different structure, a Spring Boot jar isn't useable as a dependency. If this isn't a standalone application, don;t create an executable jar, but a regular one, else create 2 artifacts as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)

Comment: @M.Deinum i tried with regular jar also, same funcationality will works fine if i create library project as maven but same is not working in gradle project

Comment: Your gradle project is creating a spring boot jar NOT a regular jar. Remove the spring-boot plugin and only use the dependency plugin.

Comment: but if i create a regular jar then also it is not working i created spring boot jar for testing purpose only,

Comment: What isn't working? Please clarify? Just adding a jar **can** be enough, **but** if your package isn't covered by the default `@ComponentScan` it will obviously not work.

Comment: i explicitly specified @ComponentScan also

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following gradle section in order to achieve this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.aaa.bbb.SpringBootApplication'
    }
}
```

Comment: add your build.gradle file and also the stacktrace that you receive when you try to build your project